# Symplectic reduction and canonical one form

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, poisson-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth manifold. Then $T^*X$ is canonically a symplectic manifold. Let $\alpha$ denote the canonical one form on $T^*X$ (so in local coordinates, $\alpha=\sum p_i dq_i$). Then the symplectic form is given by $\beta=d\alpha$.

Now suppose we have a free proper action of a Lie group $G$ on $X$. Then we get a Hamiltonian action of $G$ on $T^*X$ and the quotient $Y=(T^*X)/G$ is canonically a Poisson manifold. Thus, we have a $2$-vector $\psi\in H^0(Y, \wedge^2 TM)$ satisfying an appropriate integrability condition.

Question 1: How do we describe $\psi$ in terms of $\alpha$?

Next, let C be a symplectic leaf of $Y$. Let $\gamma=\gamma_C$ denote the symplectic form on $C$.

Question 2: How do we describe $\gamma$ in terms of $\alpha$?